# Match a string that doesn't contain another string in Bash?

Tags: regex, bash

I want to match a string that contains some text in the beginning and end but doesn't contain a different text in the middle. For example: starts with a word (\w+) and ends with another one but doesn't contain `NOT` in between:

```
some_YES_text   // ok
other_COOL_string  // also ok
some_NOT_string   // don't want to match this
```

Normally, I could do that with negative lookahead:

```
\w+_(?!NOT)\w+_\w+
```

But I'm writing a script in Bash which doesn't support it. What is the easiest way to achieve the same effect?

Edit: I wasn't precise before - I still need to use regex, not just plain text matching.

Comment: Note: a PCRE regex should actually be `\w+_(?!NOT_)\w+_\w+`. Well, I am not sure now if you actually need to match letters, digits *and underscores*  before and after `_..._`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match `abc_NOT_def` *or* `abc_anywordhere_def` and capture one of them, or part of them, and upon a match, check if that capture is not empty. Then, just implement the logic you need:

```
s="other_NOT_string"
rx='^([[:alnum:]_]+_(NOT)_[[:alnum:]_]+|[[:alnum:]_]+_[[:alnum:]_]+_[[:alnum:]_]+)$'
if [[ "$s" =~ $rx ]]; then
 if [ -z ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} ]; then 
   echo "MATCH: ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
 else
   echo "No match"
 fi;
else
 echo "No match" 
fi;
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(` - Start of Group 1:

  - `[[:alnum:]_]+_` - 1+ word chars (POSIX ERE `\w` equivalent) and a `_`
  - `(NOT)` - Group 2: `NOT`
  - `_[[:alnum:]_]+`  - `_` and 1+ word chars
  - `|` - or
  - `[[:alnum:]_]+_[[:alnum:]_]+_[[:alnum:]_]+` - 1+ word chars, `_`, 1+ word chars, `_` and again 1+ word chars
- `)` - end of Group 1.
- `$` - end of string

With `[ -z ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} ]` condition, we check if `NOT` was matched. If it was, there is no valid match, else, there is one.

Comment: FYI: If you do not want to allow any `_` before and after `_..._`, remove `_` from all `[[:alnum:]_]`s. If you do not want a whole string match, remove `^` and `$`. The idea is still valid in those scenarios, too: you match and capture a part of an alternation where the first one is more specific and the other one is more generic, and apply additional logic in the script to check if the match is valid for you.

Comment: Group 1 (for the alternatives) doesn't seem necessary. Is it? (Either way, this idea is probably the best approach, thank you.)

Comment: @NPS If you need to match the whole string matching the pattern, Group 1 is crucial, else, the anchors will only get applied to different alternatives each.

Comment: Good point. But writing the anchors twice (for each alternative) would work too?

Comment: @NPS Yes, but that is not a good practice. And unfortunately, POSIX ERE does not support non-capturing groups.

Comment: @NPS Imagine you have 5, 10 or 15 alternatives, you can easily miss one or two anchors and it will be difficult to quickly spot them.